# How to Add underline to the text which searched through contains()

Tags: jquery

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
<script>
$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>
```

The above code will add underline to the total DIV which contains "John".But how can i make only "John" to be underlined.
Please someone help me.

Comment: you need to rewrite corresponding div, e.g. add span to enclose searched word

Comment: I am not sure if you should use underlines on a web page for anything else but hyperlinks. At least I am really annoyed when I try and click something which looks like a link but isn't.

Comment: Have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/fkling/jquery_playground/blob/master/jquery_text_highlight.js) I wrote. You could use it and style the matched words accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your text in a span:

```
$("div:contains('John')").each(function()
{
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.html( $el.html().replace(/John/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">John</span>') );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GP96T/2/

As noted by @Brad Christie, you should only use this if you either know that you don't have "John" somewhere in your attributes, or the `div`s have no children.

Comment: It's a bit weird to first add a class and then style it through jQuery. I'd either put `.underline` in your stylesheet or just put an empty `span` and give it an inline style with `text-decoration:underline;`.

Comment: @Kokos: I would put it in the stylesheet. It just seems that, for whatever reason, the OP didn't want it so, or else he would have just added a class of underline himself...

Comment: You and @JJ both have code that, from what I can see, would only work in cases of one match. Considering the OP provides an example that includes two matching `<div>` I think this should be fixed to work on a collection. -- EDIT: Also, JS regex shouldn't be encapsulated in a single quote.

Comment: @All: Updated with inline styles, and support for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead:

```
$oldcontent = $("div:contains('John')").html();
$("div:contains('John')").html($oldcontent.replace('John', '<u>John</u>');
```

Comment: Same goes with @Joesph, please fix to work on a collection of items, not on a single matching div.

Answer (score -1):

Hackish way:

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
<script>
    $("div:contains('John')").each(function(i,e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var html = $this.html()
            .replace(/John/g,'<span style="text-decoration:underline;">John</span>');
        $this.html(html);
    });
</script>
```

As Seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/h6uVJ/)

But be careful, if you have "John" in a link, or a title tag, this will also replace those instances as well. e.g.

```
<div><img src="..." title="This is John" /></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div><img src="..." title="This is <span style="text-decoration:underline;">John</span>" /></div>
```

*(undesirable I would imagine)*

Comment: `.replace('John',...` will only do so for the first instance of "John". To ascertain that we get all of them, we should use `/John/g`.